# What other protocols can be used with SIP other than SDP?

Tags: sip

What are the other protocols that can be used with SIP other than SDP?

I tried to search this online and couldn't find a single call flow that describes this scenario.

Comment: If you mean what payloads can go in the body of a SIP request the answer is anything you want. SDP is the typical payload or an INVITE request but you could use XML, HTML, JPEG etc. etc. but of course the receiving SIP agent would need to know how to handle the payload.

Answer (score 2):

In a SIP request you have headers and payload.
The payload can be anything you want, because you can define the Content-Type of the payload in the respective header.

For instance, SDP is used to negotiate media for calls and when you send it on a request/answer, the Content-Type header is set to `application/sdp`.

If you want to send a XML, you can set the Content-Type as application/xml...

The content is not limited to contents with text representation. Basically you write bytes in the body and define the Content-Type accordingly. The Content-Length header will tell you how many bytes you are supposed to read from the start of the payload and then you deal with the bytes the way you want.

Note1: SIP protocol allows all of this. Of course, for you to use proprietary contents, You need to have some control on the server side, if you need server to understand what you are sending.

Note2: If your question is to find another way to negotiate calls using SIP, the standard one is SDP and it is the format that every SIP servers understand. But you can use anything else, if you are also creating the SIP side.